# strange collection of extra bones that connects to already existing bones

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, avatar

So I'm learning how to add characters with a rig. I made a simple box character in blender and gave it a rig. It worked as intended in Blender. I could not find extra bones or anything that could relate to the result in Unity.
The Animator does let me rotate and move the parts of the character. The animator does show a lot of problems like bones that don't exist, even tho they do exist.

This mess of bones also shows up on models without a skeleton.
What causes this and how can I make it so it only takes the actual skeleton?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Extra bones could be just an artifact from the bone rendering addon that you're using. The animator might be complaining if you attach it to the wrong gameobject in the prefab hirarchy. It would be easier to assist you, if you could provide the model in question.

Comment: @Voidsay How do I provide the model? Is it the blender model or the Unity version? I also did not attach the animator at all, it was already there. I accessed it right from the prefab.

Comment: the sourefile that you passed to unity in whatever format that is. In my typical workflow I have to attach the animator, you're probably using the native .blen format so that might be the difference.